In angular material calendar, how do you add borders to all date cells including the empty ones
I'm using angular material calendar and I want to add empty cells with borders whenever the day does not fall on the first day of the week. I also want to add empty cells at the end of the calendar day whenever the day does not fall on the last day of the week
can't find any code or sample regarding it

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

<mat-calendar [headerComponent]="headerComponent" [selected]="_selectedDate [startAt]="_selectedDate" [dateClass]="dateClass"
(selectedChange)="onSelectedChange($event)"  [dateFilter]="dateFilter"
>
on the css side, I added these to add borders to the cells:
.mat-calendar-body-cell {
border: 1px solid #C4CDD5;
padding-top: 6.1% !important;
padding-bottom: 6.1% !important;
All the days with values have border but I wanted to add borders to those empty cells at the beginning and end of the calendar , any idea how to do that?

for those months where the start/end day does not fall on first/last day of the week
